# For loop only goes through one iteration in python

Tags: python, nested-loops

```
stat_to_grid_dist = []
for a in xrange(99):
    stat_to_grid_dist_colm = []
    for k in xrange(22):
        stat_to_grid_dist_row = []
        for l in xrange(28):
            stat_to_grid_dist_row.append(math.sqrt(
                math.pow(x_station[a]-xpt_grid[k],2) +
                math.pow(y_station[a]-ypt_grid[l],2)
            ))
        stat_to_grid_dist_colm.append(stat_to_grid_dist_row)
    stat_to_grid_dist.append(stat_to_grid_dist_colm)
```

When using the above, the first for loop (the `a` for loop) only moves through the loop once. I can access anything in the `stat_to_grid_dist` list for the `stat_to_grid_dist[0][k][l]`, and when I put a print statement for a anywhere in the loop it only outputs zero. I can't seem to figure out what is happening. Am I incorrectly understanding how to append to a list of list of lists?

Comment: is this loops in a function ?

Comment: Can you also post a minimal example of your data including x_station , y_station, xpt_grid and ypt_grid. Your could take a subset of that data and change the ranges so the code example is functional. That makes the answer much easier to be adressed.

Comment: x_station and y_station are each lists that are 99 long. xpt_grid is 22 long, and ypt_grid is 28 long lists. They are simply each a list of floats. I've checked each, and they are completely correct for what I need. I can post the data, but it is simply just a list of numbers :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print out a 99 times. I don't know anything about your data though:

```py
import math

x_station = range(1,100)
y_station = range(1,100)
xpt_grid = range(1,23)
ypt_grid = range(1,29)

stat_to_grid_dist = []
for a in xrange(99):
    stat_to_grid_dist_colm = []
    for k in xrange(22):
        stat_to_grid_dist_row = []
        for l in xrange(28):
            stat_to_grid_dist_row.append(
            math.sqrt(math.pow(x_station[a]-xpt_grid[k],2) + 
            math.pow(y_station[a]-ypt_grid[l],2)))
        stat_to_grid_dist_colm.append(stat_to_grid_dist_row)
    stat_to_grid_dist.append(stat_to_grid_dist_colm)
    print a
```

Comment: So I tested this example on my machine and it worked as well. As I stated in a comment above, x_station, y_station, xpt_grid, and ypt_grid are each just a list of floats that are just numbers (as you could probably guess, they represent distances). I could give you the data, but it is just simply numbers (floats, to be specific).

Comment: I figured out what was happening. It was a silly error that has nothing to do with the posted above, but this helped me get to it. Thank you for your response, though I'm a bit sad to find that this community seems very hostile for anyone new. I think I'll stick to other venues in the future.

Comment: Ok I hope it helped a little. I have the exact same concerns as you about the hostility here. This is really sad. Maybe one can finde something better...